# What is `ContractTransaction`?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, bignumber

I have a function in my smart contract:

```js
function provideLiquidity(address inputToken, uint256 amount)
        external
        override
        onlyValidAddress(inputToken)
        whenNotPaused
        returns (uint256) {}
```

I'm writing a test case for this function.

```js
var plOutput = await pl.provideLiquidity(tC.address, amount);
```

Should this not return a BigInt?

This returns a `ContractTransaction` -

```js
provideLiquidity(
    inputToken: string,
    amount: BigNumberish,
    overrides?: Overrides & { from?: string | Promise<string> }
  ): Promise<ContractTransaction>;
```

How do I get a BigInt from this function? I want to use the `uint256` return from this function.

Answer (score 1):

A `ContractTransaction` is returned, because the method is state changing (e.g. not marked as `view` or `pure` on the contract).

With Ethers you can use `callStatic` to retrieve the return value of a state changing method (see https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-callStatic)